# Can I determine if a given "hostname" is a CNAME via Perl

Tags: perl, dns, cname

At work I have something like this...

```
$ host www.something.com
www.something.com is an alias for some.other.address
some.other.address is an alias for one.more.address
one.more.address has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I would like a way, in Perl to put in `www.something.com` and determine if it's a CNAME, A record, etc.

Comment: A quick google of "perl DNS" comes up with ... http://www.net-dns.org/

Comment: Going directly to CPAN: [Net::DNS](http://p3rl.org/Net::DNS), [Net::DNS::SEC](http://p3rl.org/Net::DNS::SEC)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
use Net::DNS qw();
my $query = Net::DNS::Resolver->new->search('conferences.yapceurope.org');

if ($query) {
    foreach my $rr ($query->answer) {
        next unless 'CNAME' eq $rr->type;
        print $rr->cname;
    }
} else {
    warn sprintf "query failed: %s\n", $res->errorstring;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The Net::DNS documentation I found was pretty weak. Works like a champ.

Comment: FWIW - the documentation on cpan isn't bad - the above is directly from it http://search.cpan.org/~nlnetlabs/Net-DNS-0.81/lib/Net/DNS.pm#Look_up_a_host%27s_addresses.